# .htaccess image display problem

Tags: image, .htaccess, directory

htaccess file to redirect my pages like

site/pageTitle to index.php?id=pt

and to show article from category 
site/article/pageTitle

now .htaccess file considering my image folder as catgory directory and images as pageTitle and does not display images 
even when I direct url to image it shows article page

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


#show urls like site/author/pageno

RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?author=$1&page=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)?$  index.php?author=$1&page=$2 [NC]

#show articles like site/article/articleTagName

RewriteRule ^article/(.*)/(.*)?$  index.php?article=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)?$  index.php?article=$1 [NC]


#direst article  site/articleTagName
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?article=$1 [L,QSA] 



#set image folder and user folder to real from virtual
RewriteRule ^(.*)/images/$ /images/
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your last line with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/images/(.*)$ images/$2
```

I was facing the same problem but I got a hint from your coding and changed the code a little bit; now it's working fine.

Comment: if my path = www.test.com/img/test/12.jpg
correct path is resource/image/test/12.jpg
can i write like this?
RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/$ resource/image/$1